# Photos do not save after I rotate them in Ristretto

Tags: linux, jpeg, ristretto

The photos I am trying to rotate are JPEGs. I open them in Ristretto and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. Even if I press "save copy", the rotated image doesn't get saved to disk! Why?

All files have 777 permissions to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Ristretto [does not support](http://docs.xfce.org/apps/ristretto/getting-started) saving rotated images:

> Ristretto does not provide a way to save the altered orientation back into the file. If you want to modify the image-data, this needs to be done with an image-editor, like The GIMP.

That much I can say. As for the alternatives, that's getting off-topic for this forum. If you search the web for a few minutes you'll find something :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to rotate and save some images using `Ristretto` in xubuntu. I landed here and thanks to [@misha256's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1016436/633567) I learned that it is just not possible to save the rotated images.

I started looking for alternative software, and found that `gthumb` (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gthumb) did it nice and in a practical way, since it allows to see all images in a folder and rotate those which need them one after the other (without having to open every one separately).

While I realise that this does not solve the original issue (save rotated images in `ristretto`), I decided to include my personal solution here for future references.

Comment: Why don't you provide more explanation to OP

Comment: Welcome to superuser, could please add more detail to your answer and how it helps the OP(if not it could be deleted as an "i have this trouble to answer" and it is more of a comment). Please take a couple of minutes and read:-  http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer,again welcome to superuser and don't stop helping.Thankyou –